# Python NumPy calculate the sum

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a **P** array  which represents  6 forces (weights):

```
P = np.array([3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12])
```

I have a **d** array WHICH represents the distances between the forces and the origin (0)

```
d = np.array([0, 4.5, 6, 10.5, 15, 16.5])
```

I want to calculate  the Sum of Pl(i)*d(i ) for each value of **i**

**i** is an index from 2 to 4 ( 2 iterations : 2 and 3 ,4 not included  )

**Pl(i)**  are the forces that are located to the left of Pi

**d(i)**  are the distances of the forces located to the left of Pi **to** Pi

example :for i = 2 :
P2 = the third value of P (index start at 0 ) = 6

Pl(2) = are 3 and  4

d(i) = 6-0 = **6** and 6- 4.5 = **1.5**

The Sum of Pl(i)*d(i ) = (3 * 6) + (4 * 1.5)  = 24

I tried :

```
Di = np.array([])
Pl = np.array([])
for x in range(2,4):
   Pl = P[:x]
   Pl = np.append(Pl, P[:x])

     
  for i in range (0,x):
               di = d[x]-d[i]
               Di = np.append(Di, di)
```

it kind of works but its giving one array example for Di :

Di[ 6. 1.5 10.5 6. 4.5]

I want to have :

D2 =[ 6. 1.5]  for i=2
D3 =[10.5 6. 4.5] for i=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the code below should give you the expected sum results for each iteration

```
import numpy as np

forces_sum = []
for i in range(2,4):
    Pi = P[:i]
    Di = d[i] - d[:i]
    forces_sum.append(np.sum(Pi * Di))
```

Edit:
In case you want also Pi and Di used in each iteration:

```
forces_sum = []
Pi = []
Di = []
for i in range(2,4):
    Pi.append(P[:i])
    Di.append(d[i] - d[:i])
    forces_sum.append(np.sum(Pi[-1] * Di[-1]))
```

Comment: thank you this is correct   but i want to have  two arrays of Pi and two arrays of Di  an array for each itération  so i can show wich  Pi  is multiplied with Di for each itération

Comment: Alright, I've edited the answer with a slight modification to also store Pi and Di on each iteration.